A recurrence relationship for Padé approximants of rational functions
I have a complex rational function
$$h(s) = \frac{ f(s) }{ g(s) } = \frac{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f[k] s^k } { \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g[k] s^k }$$
where $f[k]$ is the kth coefficient and the power series.  Of note, $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ converge slowly.  A book I have suggests constructing a Padé approximant $\frac{ P(s) } { Q(s) }$ to match the rational function and give better convergence properties.
I've implemented this with a modification of the normal matrix method for solving Pade approximants to find the coefficients $P[k], Q[k]$.  This works well and gives the correct answer to a pretty high precision with only a handful of terms.
However it can be slow, and I'm working on a real-time application where I'd gladly trade some precision for some performance.  The book I have suggests that the Pade approximants can also be built using a recurrence relationship:
$$ P_{n+1}(s) = P_n(s) + a_{n+1} s P_{n-1}(s) $$
$$ Q_{n+1}(s) = Q_n(s) + a_{n+1} s Q_{n-1}(s) $$
where $a_{n+1} = -\frac{r_n}{r_{n-1}}$ and
$$ r_n = \sum_{k=0}^n Q_n[k] f[n+1-k] - P_n[k] g[n+1-k]$$
$$ P_{-1}(s) = 0, Q_{-1}(s) = 1$$
$$ P_{0}(s) = \frac{f_0}{g_0}, Q_{0}(s) = 1$$
I've implemented this and it gives me different (wrong) answers from the matrix method, though they're close.  I've gone through the derivation a few times and what I'm getting agrees with the book.  Likewise with my implementation.
Is this recurrence method called something that I could look up in a book?  It's possible I'm missingly something obvious.  A second source to compare my derivation against might help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  As I understand it the Padé approximants of a given order are unique so I shouldn't be getting different results with different methods.
